# How do I stretch a background image to cover the entire HTML element?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to get a background image of a HTML element (body, div, etc.) to stretch its entire width and height.

Not having much luck. Is it even possible or do I have to do it some other way besides it being a background image?

My current css is:

```
body {
    background-position: left top;
    background-image: url(_images/home.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Edit: I'm not keen on maintaining the CSS in Gabriel's suggestion so I'm changing the layout of the page instead. But that seems like the best answer so I'm marking it as such.

Comment: Of course, you could use JavaScript to do this dynamically, but that would be probably worse than the CSS hacks suggested by gabriel1836's link.

Comment: To preserve the aspect ratio of the image you should use "background-size: cover;" or "background-size: contain;". I've built a polyfill that implements those values in IE8: http://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill

Answer (score 215, accepted):

```
<style>
    { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

    html { 
        background: url('images/yourimage.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: This also works as style tags within html elements or in css files.

Comment: this is the best solution, ever.

Comment: What's the difference between cover vs 100% 100% ?

Comment: 100% 100% does not keep the aspect ratio of the original image.
‘cover’ scales the image, while preserving its intrinsic aspect ratio (if any), to the smallest size such that both its width and its height can completely cover the background positioning area. You can also use ‘contain’ to scale the image, while preserving its intrinsic aspect ratio (if any), to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the background positioning area.

Comment: "-webkit-background-size: cover;" is not a valid CSS3 property.

Comment: The background-size property is supported in IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome, and Safari 5+ - So browser prefixes should be unnecessary. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: [More detailed list of supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) also check [IE 7-8 polyfill](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill)

Comment: If you need, add `height:100%` to html.

Comment: @Nathan sorry for the downvote, I misclicked but I noticed it too late

Comment: This doesn't *shrink* images. It only enlarges them. To make the image always exactly the same size as the element use `background-size: 100% 100%`.

Comment: `{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }` without any proceeding selector is **invalid**.

Comment: It didn't work until I changed `html {}` with `body {}`

Answer (score 15):

Use the `background-size` property: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size

Comment: Awesome, this is the correct answer. It probably doesn't work on IE, but I'm only targeting webkit for my project, so this is perfect :)

Answer (score 9):

In short you can try this....

```
<div data-role="page" style="background:url('backgrnd.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%;" >
```

Where I have used few css and js...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

And it is working fine for me.

Comment: For those who do NOT want to keep the aspect ratio!

Answer (score 6):

Not sure that stretching a background image is possible.  If you find that it's not possible, or not reliable in all of your target browsers, you could try using a stretched img tag with z-index set lower, and position set to absolute so that other content appears on top of it.

Let us know what you end up doing.

Edit: What I suggested is basically what's in gabriel's link.  So try that :)

Comment: I saw this technique in action at least a decade ago. I can't imagine it wouldn't still work now.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on @PhiLho answer, you can center a very large image (or any size image) on a page with:

```
{ 
background-image: url(_images/home.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center; 
}
```

Or you could use a smaller image with a background color that matches the background of the image (if it is a solid color). This may or may not suit your purposes.

```
{ 
background-color: green;
background-image: url(_images/home.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center; 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to stretch your background image while resizing the screen and you don't need compatibility with older browser versions this will do the work:

```
body {
    background-image: url('../images/image.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a large landscape image, this example here resizes the background in portrait mode, so that it displays on top, leaving blank on the bottom:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-image: url('myimage.jpg');
    background-position-x: center;
    background-position-y: bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    body {
        background-position-y: top;
        -webkit-background-size: contain;
        -moz-background-size: contain;
        -o-background-size: contain;
        background-size: contain;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code I use mostly for achieving the asked effect:

```
body {
    background-image: url('../images/bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You need `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Comment: I don't know what browser you use, But what I have told works for me in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

```
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 2):

It works for me

```
.page-bg {
  background: url("res://background");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example from my code:

```css
.content{
  background-image: url("SOMEURL");
  background-position:center;
  background-size: cover;

  text-align: center; /* Center-aligns text horizontally */
  justify-content: center; /* Center content horizontally */

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot in pure CSS. Having an image covering the whole page behind all other components is probably your best bet (looks like that's the solution given above). Anyway, chances are it will look awful anyway. I would try either an image big enough to cover most screen resolutions (say up to 1600x1200, above it is scarcer), to limit the width of the page, or just to use an image that tile.

Answer (score 0):

image{

```
background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 0 3em 0 3em; 
margin: -1.5em -0.5em -0.5em -1em; 
  width: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! To write a better answer, add some reasoning as to why it works and show the code in action. You can also read about [writing a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a div to be the direct child of body (with the class name bg for example), encompassing all other elements in the body, and add this to the CSS file:

```
.bg {
    background-image: url('_images/home.jpg');//Put your appropriate image URL here
    background-size: 100% 100%; //You need to put 100% twice here to stretch width and height
}
```

Refer to this link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp
Scroll down to the part that says:

> 2. If the background-size property is set to "100% 100%", the background image will stretch to cover the entire content area

There it shows the 'img_flowers.jpg' stretching to the size of the screen or browser regardless of how you resize it.