# CSS3 - Multiple backgrounds that covering the whole site

Tags: css, image, background, cover

I was wondering how it could be possible to set multiple background one below the other that cover the whole site. I mean something like this: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/reaper-of-souls/

I simplay couldn't find a solution yet but it actually seems so simple :(

Comment: I just checked out Google but couldn't find a suitable solution yet.

Comment: Also, there's only one background image on this page.

Comment: I mean the different separated "wrapper" like http://us.battle.net/d3/static/images/reaper-of-souls/bg/section-game-intro.jpg

Answer (score 1):

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U8LLG/)

You can use the `background: background1, background2, ...;` property to display 2 backgrounds on top of each other. Here I used 2 PNGs as background on top of each other. They look weird because I used size 100% 100%

**CSS**

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    background: url('http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2013/082/a/c/png_grass_by_moonglowlilly-d5z1o5t.png') left top/100% 100% no-repeat,
        url('http://th05.deviantart.net/fs70/PRE/f/2013/120/7/b/png_monsters_inc_by_upinflames12-d63nx7i.png') left top/100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I add and positionate text on each picture?

Comment: What so you mean by `each` picture? You can write anything inside a `p` tag and style it, it'll be over the body and thus over the background (the 2 images) of body. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/U8LLG/1/show/

Comment: Well the title of that website is another image in a container `h1` and the container is centered inside its own container. The FX you see are done using `video` tag. The best way to know how that website is working is to dive into its source.

Comment: I speak of the parts below the video header, I just need to know how to place pictures one below the other and then add and positionate text on it.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/U8LLG/2/show/ If you want to add another picture in background, you can add another background in `background` property

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204275/what-does-an-asterisk-do-in-a-css-selector

Answer (score 0):

try creating several divisions, one on top of the other on `position absolute` or `fixed`, `width:100% height:100%`, each division with its own `background`, you will need to make the `html and body 100%`:

CSS:

```
html, body{
   height:100%
}

#div1{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 z-index:-1;
 background:(your background properties)
}

#div2{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 z-index:-2;
 background:(your background properties)
}

#div3{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 z-index:-3;
 background:(your background properties)
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

For them to appear on top of each other they will need to be transparent pngs or have opacities. You can also add a background to the body to add another layer

Answer (score 0):

To acheive this, what I have done till now and what I know is, there is no possible way to add two `background`s as of now. So, I make two `div` say *header* and *footer*, then I apply the background over it. And possibly a third `div` to form a body. Setting the `CSS` `position` to `absolute` you can easily acheive an overlapping look.

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="body"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

For CSS you can have this.

```
#header, #body, #footer
{
    background: url("img1.jpg");
    position: absolute;
}
```

Most of the website do this.

Try this. This might work for you.

```
<style>
body
{
    margin: 0px;
}
div
{
    height: 33.3%;
}
#header
{
        background: url("1.jpg");
}
#footer
{
    background: url("2.jpg");
}
#body
{
        background: url("3.jpg");
}
</style>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="body"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: This is what I also tried but for me there was always a white border around the picture and it looked as if the picture was in a div.

Comment: You can set the `padding` of div to `0px` and `margin` of pic to `0px`

Comment: and do set the `body{margin:0px;}` in your CSS

Comment: Is there no possibility to set a "cover" tag to make the image cover the whole browser windows?

Comment: din't get you. `cover` tag..?? can you give me some example.? I am in office so, they have blocked the above link categorized in `games`. So, please provide me with some other link.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235855/how-do-i-stretch-a-background-image-to-cover-the-entire-html-element) question might work for you.

Comment: I mean something like the background-size: cover; tag

Comment: The problem is that the second picture is on the first picture, I can't get managed to make the second picture BELOW the first!