# HTML: background-image not displaying

Tags: html, image, background

I wanted a specific `div` of mine to have its own specific background with the width of 100% so it's covering the entire `div`, why won't the background image show.
[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/huspk2j1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add height and width property in order you want to use a background-image.

```
#counter1 {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/7NMEPIo.jpg);
    width:600px;height:340px;
}
```

[here is a fiddle with a working version](http://jsfiddle.net/huspk2j1/4/)

You should reconsider using other font colors ;-)

Comment: Hello and thank you for the answer, just a very small question if I may. I would like to make the width for my picture to be 100% so all along the site, and for it to no-repeat. However every time I do so it will only cover 25% of the site, do you think you know the answer? [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/huspk2j1/14/)

Comment: Maybe this can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235855/how-do-i-stretch-a-background-image-to-cover-the-entire-html-element

Answer (score 0):

Element with `id=counter1` has no content* (`float` move elements out of document flow), div's height is 0 and it's reason why you don't see backgrond image.

```
#counter1 {overflow: hidden}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/huspk2j1/9/

*)
Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/huspk2j1/11/, I've added `border: 1px solid blue` to `#counter1` to show you it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

Basically because the floating counters don't cause it's parent to calculate height properly. You can fix this with a `overflow: hidden` property.

```
#counter1 {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/7NMEPIo.jpg);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/huspk2j1/8/

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this you can simply add an element with `clear: both` at the end of your container.

See updated code here: http://jsfiddle.net/aksruLLh.

Comment: You'd need more markup for this. I'd argue the `overflow` method is cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
#counter1:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

to your css.

See http://jsfiddle.net/huspk2j1/12/