# How to have a backround image on HTML

Tags: html

Good afternoon,

I want to a have a backround image on my HTML file but having issues in doing this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<style>
body {
  background-image: src('img_BD1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<img src="./img/BD1.jpg"/>
<a href="student.php">Student data</a>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my coding and I know the <img src=2./img/BD1.jpg"/> works but only as a small image and not the whole backround.

Thanks
Adam

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stretch a background image to cover the entire HTML element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235855/how-do-i-stretch-a-background-image-to-cover-the-entire-html-element)

Comment: You are not stating what's the problem

Comment: I want to know how I can do the back round image from a folder and where on the format do I need to update with the correct coding

Answer (score 0):

You should check the CSS background-size property read following.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.background-image {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src='../img/BD1.jpg' class='background-image' />
```

That should do what your looking for

Answer (score -1):

You should place the background image in the html element because it always is at least the window height (the body element isn't).
Then you can use one of the following options to make it cover the whole background:

```css
background-size: auto;

background-size: cover;
```

You also can center and fix the background image like this:

```css
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

If you want to be sure that it works in every browser you can use the following CSS:

```css
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Thank you as I have found that it was all related to .xampp not accepting where the image file was kept but it has worked now after playing around with it for few days.